# haystack order_by not in proper

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I am using django1.8 and haystack 2.4 and solr 4.10. Somehow order_by is not working as expected, Please have a look at below code,

```
>>> sqs = SearchQuerySet()
>>> sqs = sqs.using('entry').filter(status=0)
>>> for b in sqs.filter(content="see").order_by('title'): print b.title
501 Must-See Movies
Look See, Look at Me!
Last Chance to See
1,000 Places to See Before You Die
Pretend You Don't See Her
Learning to See Creatively : Design, Color and Composition in Photography
Behavior Solutions for the Inclusive Classroom : See a Behavior? Look It Up!
See No Evil
Last Chance to See
See It and Sink It : Mastering Putting Through Peak Visual Performance
See No Evil : The True Story of a Ground Soldier in the CIA's War on Terrorism
Voice for Now : Changing the Way We See Ourselves As Women
See Jane Win : The Rimm Report on How 1,000 Girls Became Successful Women
Kaplan Medical USMLE Medical Ethics : The 100 Cases You Are Most Likely to See on the Exam
I See You
You'll See It When You Believe It : The Way to Your Personal Transformation
Body Code : Diet and Fitness Programme: Master Your Metabolism and See the Weight Fall Off
```

descending Order

```
>>> sqs = SearchQuerySet()
>>> sqs = sqs.using('entry').filter(status=0)
>>> for b in sqs.filter(content="see").order_by('-title'): print b.title
You'll See It When You Believe It : The Way to Your Personal Transformation
Body Code : Diet and Fitness Programme: Master Your Metabolism and See the Weight Fall Off
Kaplan Medical USMLE Medical Ethics : The 100 Cases You Are Most Likely to See on the Exam
I See You
Voice for Now : Changing the Way We See Ourselves As Women
See Jane Win : The Rimm Report on How 1,000 Girls Became Successful Women
See No Evil : The True Story of a Ground Soldier in the CIA's War on Terrorism
See It and Sink It : Mastering Putting Through Peak Visual Performance
Last Chance to See
See No Evil
Behavior Solutions for the Inclusive Classroom : See a Behavior? Look It Up!
Learning to See Creatively : Design, Color and Composition in Photography
Pretend You Don't See Her
1,000 Places to See Before You Die
Last Chance to See
Look See, Look at Me!
501 Must-See Movies
```

Why odering is not working like A --> Z and Z --> A

Comment: How are you populating title? Something does seem amiss here.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr You mean Indexes ? I can't follow your qiestion.

Comment: Yes, how are you creating your indexes?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr normal way.. search_indexes.py and export the schema.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Recently i had same issue with haystack order_by for title. I used python lambda function to sort object list.

ascending order using title:

```
sqs = sqs.using('entry').filter(status=0)
sorted_list = sorted([s.object for s in sqs], key=lambda x: x.title, reverse=False)
```

descending order:

```
sqs = sqs.using('entry').filter(status=0)
    rev_sorted_list = sorted([s.object for s in sqs], key=lambda x: x.title, reverse=True)
```

sqs.order_by works very well with Integer fields.